# Is it possible to make the design of a C# application with CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am better in creating a computer based application in C# than a webpage in ASP.net. But the power that CSS has in designing buttons, form, etc.. really makes me love it.

I was searching on google if I can use just CSS in a software but no result yet. 
Is it possible? 
I know this is too abroad and kinda stupid question, but I really need an answer.

EDIT:
I would like to mention that I use Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. Obviously it's possible to use CSS in ASP.NET (which is the platform you tagged). Are you talking about other platforms too (like desktop applications or mobile apps)?

Comment: Something like: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14814/StylesSheetManager-A-CSS-like-component-for-WinFor You may look into WPF as well - much more design-friendly than WinForms

Comment: Hey @EJoshuaS I am trying to make a desktop application for my dad company. Simple data entry software, but I'm trying to make it look professional too. with the basic design that you are able to use in Visual Studio the software looks really "boring", borders, cant make animations, etc.. but I can make that with css. so was wondering if can use css file to edit a desktop application design

Comment: Which platform - Windows Forms or WPF? Can you please tag your platform? You can definitely do things like animation, border styling, etc. in WPF by the way - you don't really need CSS to do those things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Use WebBroswer Class (find it in toolbox) and use your HTML and CSS codes inside that but be aware that after making all html and css strings put them in the appropriate property of the WebBrowser control. Also notice that non of server side functionalities will work. Just simple html and css.

---

Advice:
Learn how to use WPF instead of HTML and CSS for which has great power designing client side applications.

Answer (score 3):

If you really love CSS and like to create Desktop Application using CSS, you might want to look at Electron.

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) is an open-source framework developed by GitHub. *[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/c?utm_expid=101350005-27.GqBWbOBuSRqlazQC_nNSRg.2&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) and [Atom Text Editor](https://atom.io/) are created using Electron.*

You cannot use C#, but you can use Typescript which is very closed to C#.

Comment: Of course it is possible in C#, by using WebBrowser tool in C#

Comment: I have not personally tried this, but I think it's possible to run C# in a node.js process. See https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge

Comment: @media I'm talking about Electron which runs on Node.js. Steve - Electron-Edge looks interesting; I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: @media where can I find this WebBrowser. is it a tool or something?

Comment: @AnonProxy yes find it in your toolbox. after making a simple windows form application, you can find it in toolbox.

Comment: ***I'm curious why you suggest Windows Form for new application.*** Microsoft has deprecated Windows Form, and stopped the updates long time ago.

Comment: @Win what would you suggest then?

Comment: @media I kept searching over and over again, and cant find it.. the only WebBrowser I can find in my tools is the tool which allows you to access in webpages inside the page.

Comment: @AnonProxy which project template are you making? I guess you are still making ASP.NET app. As I said you should make Windows Form Application because your application does execute on desktop. Then find WebBroswer in your toolbox which can be find from View in tool bar of Visual studio

Comment: @media aha, I understood what you mean, but I'm going to focus in WPF, I'm going to try it how work. thanks!

Comment: @AnonProxy actually I have advised you in my answer to do so.

Comment: @AnonProxy Well, if you just need Window only app, you might want to look at **[Universal windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)** apps, which can be written either C#/XMAL or Javascript/HTML/CSS. Microsoft strongly encourages UWP if you are developing a new desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would recommend using [CEFSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/) which is a .NET wrapper for Chromium Embedded Framework instead of the webbrowser class. You can create programs like this:

[image: CEF inside Winforms]

Which is fully responsive, and allows javascript to C# and vice versa function calls. While not the most efficient way, it does provide a great starting foundation for using web apps in a standalone method.